# PIL: How do I enlarge an image and fit it into in a label?

Tags: python-3.x, label, python-imaging-library

I am unable to enlarge a photo and fit into in a label.

```
def displayimage(self, _event=None):
    if self.videopath != "" and self.txtsequenceframe.get() != "":
         # Placing the lable in a different location at runtime
         self.photodisplay.place(width=700, height=500, x=0, y=0)
         self.currentphoto = Image.open(self.framepaths[int(self.txtsequenceframe.get())])
         self.currentphoto.resize((700, 500), Image.ANTIALIAS)
         self.currentphotoready = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.currentphoto)
         self.photodisplay.config(image=self.currentphotoready)
```

I have searched this topic but they create a new label and place the image into there. Actually I would like to change that image many times. Can anybody help me out from this mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def displayimage(self, _event=None):
  if self.videopath != "" and self.txtsequenceframe.get() != "":
     # Placing the lable in a different location at runtime
     self.photodisplay.place(width=700, height=500, x=0, y=0)
     self.currentphoto = Image.open(self.framepaths[int(self.txtsequenceframe.get())])
     self.currentphoto = self.currentphoto.resize((700, 500), Image.ANTIALIAS)
     self.currentphotoready = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.currentphoto)
     self.photodisplay.config(image=self.currentphotoready)
```

This is the correct code. I was mistake to store resize image at the line no 6.